# Empty space at beginning of rsyslog log file

Tags: php, linux, logging, rsyslog

Using this rsyslog config:

```
$template MYFORMAT,"%msg%\n"

if $programname == 'mylog' then {
        action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/mylog.log" template="MYFORMAT")
        & stop
}
```

and this PHP script:

```
<?php
    openlog('mylog', LOG_ODELAY, LOG_LOCAL0);
    syslog(LOG_INFO, date('Y-m-d: ') . 'stuff has happened!');
    closelog();
```

My output always ends up having an empty space before the logged message (in the custom log file).

```
 2015-06-10: stuff has happened! (there's a space at the beginning of this line)
```

Answer (score 4):

Per RFC 3164, anything after the colon in the syslog tag gets counted as part of the `%msg%` field, including any space character. This is alluded to in various rsyslog documentation/blog posts, for example https://www.rsyslog.com/log-normalization-and-the-leading-space/ or the `sp-if-no-sp` documentation here https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/property_replacer.html

Since it's part of the `%msg%` field, there are two ways to log lines without a leading space:

- Hard code a prefix as part of every log line, for example:

  ```
  $template MYFORMAT,"[app]: %msg%\n"
  ```
- Strip the leading space character. You can use a `$` sign to say "include everything until the end of the line." The msg characters are 1-indexed, so start with field 2.

  ```
  $template MYFORMAT,"%msg:2:$%\n"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Modify that

```
$template MYFORMAT,"%msg%\n"
```

for

```
$template MYFORMAT,"%msg:2:2048%\n"
```

Comment: Why should it be modified like that? Maybe add some explanation, backed by documentation or so? Show what the different result will be?

Comment: substring from position 2 to 2048. I like it. Works great, and fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex based property replacer as follows:

```
template(name="logfmt" type="string" string="%msg:R,ERE,1,FIELD:^[ \t]*(.*)$--end%\n")
```

The statement above picks the 1st group (all chars after leading spaces) from MSG string matching the given regex (`^[ \t]*(.*)$`). Note that, the regex syntax is POSIX ERE (Extended Regular Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rsyslog is adding the space due it being in `date('Y-m-d: ')`

Remove the space after the colon like so:

Change

```
"syslog(LOG_INFO, date('Y-m-d: ') . 'stuff has happened!');"
```

to

```
syslog(LOG_INFO, date('Y-m-d:') . 'stuff has happened!');"
```

The php should look like this:

```
<?php
    openlog('mylog', LOG_ODELAY, LOG_LOCAL0);
    syslog(LOG_INFO, date('Y-m-d:') . 'stuff has happened!');
    closelog();
```